# Health check servlet doesn't establish connection?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to write a bare-bones health check servlet for my app, just to see if my Tomcat server is running. Essentially, it's a servlet with a "/health" endpoint that is an empty page. Below is my code:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HealthCheckServlet extends HttpServlet
{

private static final String SUCCESS = "Success";
private static final String FAILURE = "Failure";

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    isConnectionOK(request);
}

private static String isConnectionOK(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
{

    String status = "";

    try
    {
        URL connectionURL = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString() + "/health");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) connectionURL.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        int httpResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (httpResponseCode == 200)
        {
            status = SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        status = FAILURE;
    }

    return status;
}

}
```

When I navigate to localhost:8080/health and debug it, it reaches my breakpoint at `URL connectionURL = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString() + "/health");` but won't progress to any subsequent breakpoints. The page itself returns a status code of 200, so I'm just trying to get the code to pick up on that.

Am I doing something wrong with trying to establish this connection within a servlet, or is there another problem here?

Comment: Seems like localhost:8080/health keeps on calling itself again and again.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Should I not be opening the connection here?

Comment: try sending a boolean get parameter in the request, so that you can use it while deciding when to call

Comment: I don't understand what you think to achieve with this. Perhaps you didn't realize that `doGet()` would in first place already not be called when the URL is not reachable? It's therefore illogical to perform any checks to to see if itself is reachable.